# Retrieve Filename of current line in Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am using Hadoop version 2.6.4 . I was writing a MapReduce job which would take 3 arguments namely -Keyword,Path to input files and output files.
My ideal output should be names of all those files containing the keyword. 
The simple logic would be go through each line in the text and match it with our keyword. If it returns true print the filename .

After extensive googling I found 3 options to obtain the filename

1. `Context.getConfiguration().get("map.input.file")`
2. `Context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.map.input.file")`

Both methods returned a string with the value 'null' i.e they printed 'null' on my terminal screen.

3. Finally I tried this from [site.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-file-being-executed-by-the-mapper-in-hadoop-map-reduce-framework)

   ```
   public Path filesplit;
   filesplit=((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath();
   System.out.println(filesplit.getName())
   ```

The above method produced an error. The terminal output looked like this :-

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit
    at org.myorg.DistributedGrep$GrepMapper.map(DistributedGrep.java:23)
    at org.myorg.DistributedGrep$GrepMapper.map(DistributedGrep.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

1. Can anybody suggest a remedy to these errors? What might have gone wrong and are there any mistakes on my part?
2. Or do you have any other ideas of obtaining the filename of the current line being executed at the mapper.

If you want to have a full look on the code here it is

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class DistributedGrep {

    public static class GrepMapper extends
            Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
        public  Path filesplit;

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            filesplit = ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath();

            String txt = value.toString();
            String mapRegex = context.getConfiguration().get("mapregex");
//          System.out.println(context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.map.input.file");
            System.out.println(filesplit.getName());
            if (txt.matches(mapRegex)) {
                System.out.println("Matched a line");
                context.write(NullWritable.get(), value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.set("mapregex", args[0]);

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Distributed Grep");
        job.setJarByClass(DistributedGrep.class);
        job.setMapperClass(GrepMapper.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0); // Set number of reducers to zero
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Options 1 & 2**

`Context.getConfiguration().get("map.input.file")`
`Context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.map.input.file")`

I believe both of these return `null` because they should be used with the older `mapred` API and its `JobConf` configuration object. Your `#3` option is the way to do it for the `mapreduce` API.

Using the `mapred` API you would do the following:

```
public void configure(JobConf job) {
  inputFile = job.get(JobContext.MAP_INPUT_FILE);
}
```

This is shown here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html

The `JobContext.MAP_INPUT_FILE` constant value used to be `map.input.file` and was changed to `mapreduce.map.input.file` at some point.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html

**Option 3**

You're mixing MapReduce APIs. There are two the `mapred` and `mapreduce` API.

You can see this in the error you're getting:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit`

You've imported:

`import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit`

Which is from the `mapred` API, but you're using the `mapreduce` API. Change the import to:

`import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;`

One clue in your code (aside from the import) that this has happened is you've needed to add a cast to make the code compile:

`filesplit = ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath();`

This should be:

`filesplit = context.getInputSplit().getPath();`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great insights from your solution

Comment: It would be great help if you could just explain why the first 2 options didn't work out ?

Comment: Updated my answer to cover the first 2 options.